# Multi JOIN Table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables below :

**track**

```
+----+-----+----------------+-------+
| ID | TID |     TITLE      | ALBUM |
+----+-----+----------------+-------+
|  1 | AAA | Yesterday      |     1 |
|  2 | BBB | Happy          |     2 |
|  3 | CCC | Gangname Style |     3 |
+----+-----+----------------+-------+
```

**album**

```
+----+-----+---------+-------+
| ID | AID |  TITLE  | COVER |
+----+-----+---------+-------+
|  1 | AAA | Album A | 1.jpg |
|  2 | BBB | Album B | 2.jpg |
|  3 | CCC | Album C | 3.jpg |
+----+-----+---------+-------+
```

**track_artist**

```
+----+-----+-----------+
| ID | TID | ARTIST_ID |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 |   1 |         1 |
|  2 |   2 |         2 |
|  3 |   3 |         3 |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

**artist**

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID |  NAME  | AVATAR |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | Taylor | 1.JPG  |
|  2 | T-ara  | 2.JPG  |
|  3 | M2M    | 3.JPG  |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I want to get `track.TITLE`, `album.TITLE` and `artist.NAME` base on `track.TID` (`where TID = $XXX`)  in 4 table above. It's easy when I use raw INNER JOIN MySQL code, but I want to use Eloquent ORM in Laravel. How I can do this ? Thank you.

I have analyzed :

One *track* `belongsTo` one *Album*

One *track* `hasMany` *track_artist*

One *track_artist* `hasOne` *artist*

One *track* `hasMany` *artist*

Comment: Create a model for each table and do the relation.

Comment: Can you show me more detail with example, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this**

> The table should be like this, you need 4 tables

```
albums(id, title, cover)
artist(id, name, avatar)
tracks(id, album_id, title)
track_artists (id, artist_id, track_id) ManyToMany with tracks
```

> Models

```
class Album extends Model{

    function tracks(){
        $this->hasMany(Track::class);
    }
}

class Artist extends Model{

   function tracks(){
      $this->belongsToMany(Track::class, 'track_artists'); //here track_artists table is as pivot table
   }   
}

class Track extends Model{

   function album(){
        $this->belongsTo(Album::class);
   }

   function artist(){
      $this->belongsToMany(Artist::class, 'track_artists'); //here track_artists table is as pivot table
   }   
}
```

> Fetch Data

```
$track = Track::with('album','artists')->find($trackId);

echo $track->title." - ". $track->album->title;
//now print all artist of this track
foreach($track->artists as $artist){
   echo $artist->name;
}
```

**Note:** You don't need to create model for `track_artists` because it is a pivot table for `tracks` and `artists` tables. You can insert and update in pivot table using `Track` or `Artist` laravel eloquent model. Though if you want you can create it extending `Pivot`.

> Save Data in pivot table

```
$track = Track::find(1);
$artist = Artist::create(['name' => 'Katy Perry', 'avatar' => 'Katy_Perry.jpg']);
$track->artists()->save($artist); //this save track and artist relation in track_artists pivot table
```

For details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: `one` `Track` maybe have `Many` `artist` ( Something like Taylor Swift ft. Katy Perry) so I need a table `track_artist` to save them

Answer (score 0):

First, your relations ( in my opinion ) need some changes.

- One track belongs to one album and one album has many tracks (one to many)
- One track has one artist and one artist has multiple tracks (one to many)
- One album has multiple artist and one artist has multiple albums(many to many)

You will need a table for the many to many relation with the `album id` and the `artist id`

This is an example considering the above points

---

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class track extends Model{
    function album(){
        $this->belongsTo(album::class);
    }
    function artist(){
        $this->belongsTo(artist::class);
    }
}

class album extends Model{
    function track(){
        $this->hasMany(track::class);
    }
    function artist(){
        $this->belongsToMany(artist::class, 'my_many_to_many_table');
    }
}

class artist extends Model{
    function track(){
        $this->hasMany(track::class);
    }
    function album(){
        $this->belongsToMany(album::class, 'my_many_to_many_table');
    }
}
```

Comment: One track has one artist and one artist has multiple tracks (one to many). It maybe wrong. `One` `track` maybe have `many` `artist` ( Something like *Taylor Swift* ft. *Katy Perry*) so I need `track_artist` to save them.